# Production and sandbox profiles during deployment

Tags: deployment, profile, bestpractice, field-level-security

I currently maintain two sandboxes. One is a mirror of the current production. The other is a Dev Sandbox which contains all of the new development which will be included in an upcoming release. My ultimate goal is to merge these two sandboxes into a third sandbox which would represent what Production will be upon the new release.

Right now not all of the production profiles are present in the Dev Sandbox. We have been developing with profiles which were simple, just used by developers. So, I'm guessing I essentially have to move all of the used Prod profiles over to the Dev sandbox and customize each one of them to include the access settings for all the fields which will be part of the new release in order for the new fields to have the proper settings in the third sandbox. Is that correct ?

I would go about with this sequence :

1) Deploy all the used Production profiles to the Dev Sandbox

2) Go into each and every one of them and make the settings for every single components (object,field etc)which is not included in the current Prod

3) Deploy all of those now-updated Profiles to the third sandbox along with the other components (objects, fields)

Would that be the proper procedure here ? Is there a short cut which I am missing ?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems correct to me.

However, you should deploy profils thanks to Eclipse and not Change Sets.
Indeed, change Sets only add permission for content included in the package and not migrate all the profil.

Comment: Right - I do most of my deployments through Eclipse. Much quicker, and I don't know of any drawbacks. Thanks for the input Yann.

Comment: Question : If I deploy a profile from one environment to another will the only settings which change in the destination's profile be the settings for the components which I include in the deployment ?

Comment: Yes @Zoom_v. The profile metadata that will be deployed is constructed by using what is already included in your package.xml file. This is the same process at the underlying structure for all deployments from what I understand.